# Fetching vault secrets through Flyway

Tags: postgresql, flyway, vault

I am currently working on a solution that centralizes connections to external databases.

For that, I initialize a database with flyway and connect to other postgresql sources with the postrgres_fdw extension to create my table projections (with foreign tables).

Everything works fine if I put my credentials, hosts, etc... in my application.yml configuration file (we are on spring), putting these values in placeholders and reusing them in my sql migration scripts. But we want to fetch this data from vault, where we store all this data.

However, although I have followed the flyway documentation on vault integration (https://flywaydb.org/blog/integrating-vault-to-secure-flyway-parameters), I cannot achieve my goal. I've tried putting my placeholders in vault (my secrets are of the form flyway.placeholders.[...]=), and connecting to my instance via my data in my configuration file

```
spring:
  flyway:
    vault:
      url: https://localhost:8200/v1/
      token: root
      secrets: secret/data/...
```

but without success. Has anyone had this problem before? Is it possible to retrieve any secret value via placeholders to use in sql scripts or do we have to go through the java API to have a little more flexibility?

Comment: Notice Vault integration requires a Flyway Enterprise license